# Find first occurrence of 0 in a string of 1's and 0's

Tags: algorithm, search

This is a interview question:

In a sorted string of 0's and 1's , find the first occurrence of 0. The string will have one's and then followed by zero's

Eg.

```
111110  , Return value:5  
11100000 , Return value:3  
11111111, Return value:-1  
00000000, Return 0
```

**Basic approaches:**

- Linear Search : O(n)
- Binary Search to find the first occurrence of 0 : O(logn)

Is there any better solution, probably in O(1).

Interviewer gave a clue that the string can be converted to a number and then some log operations can be done, but I was unable to figure it out.

Comment: Taking the log of an integer isn't O(1) if the integer isn't constant size (which it by definition isn't here, otherwise all other approaches were also constant time)

Comment: If you take a slightly different view and count broadword operations only, then there is an O(1) algorithm, but every time I post something like that people just refuse to accept there are different ways of counting operations. Also I doubt the interviewer meant that, the algorithm neither well known nor something you could just come up with randomly.

Comment: @harold If I consider the input is an integer, Is there a chance to reduce time complexity by using bit manipulation or any other trick

Comment: If the input is an integer, there are only 32 possible values (or 64) you could map them with a hash-map function to the result. That would need O(1) time. But this will not work for Strings because to calculate a hash function of a String (which depends on all chars) you need to read al chars which costs O(n),

Comment: @mc20 if you chop the input into (log n)^k sized words (for some constant k, and k>1 is pretty generous) that you're allowed to operate on in constant time, then do binary search, you get a complexity of O(log(n/log(n)^k)), which is unfortunately the same as O(log n) anyway. So no luck there. If the input is taken as one n-bit integer, then there is the O(1)-step broadword algorithm but its steps are not constant time.

Comment: long story short, there is no better solution than log(n), converting to integer itself costs O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are n+1 different strings and possible results, so the quantity of information needed (that is the minimum number of tests your program must make) to provide the correct answer is O(ln n).

This is an occurence of the "find first bit set" problem discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set

Comment: add an example to explain this please :)

Comment: There are popular tricks with the binary représentation of numbers, but converting the string to a number is O(n) itself.

Comment: @MichelBillaud that's not the problem. You can just assume it's already an integer, an interpretation switch like that doesn't count. But it doesn't really matter, if you have the integer there's still no constant time solution.

Comment: Of course there is. Use the number as an index in a table of size 2^N (most places will be unused)

Comment: @MichelBillaud oh sure, use an infinite size table, now go write a paper about how you've bested Fürer's algorithm for integer multiplication because obviously you can extend the technique to that

Comment: @MichelBillaud I miss your point, can you please explain the above comment, if we consider input as a interger.

Comment: For N=3, there are 4 strings : 111 (aka 7), 110 (6), 100 (4) and 000 (0). The following table will do the trick { 0, ?, ?, ?, 1, ?, 2,  -1} question marks are unused.

Comment: @harold Using a pre-computed lookup table is a common strategy. Teime/Space tradeoff

Comment: It is, but it's not legitimate to index a pre-computed table with an *n-bit* integer in constant time. Among other things, it would allow you to factor semi-primes in constant time.

Comment: Are we discussing a practical problem or a theoretical one ?  Which size  n are we talking about ? What do we consider as a "too large" table ?

Comment: Theoretical, right? Any n? Obviously if you limit n to a constant (say 64), all of this can be done in constant time - but then so could the original problem on a string, because that string was necessarily also constant length (or else it wouldn't fit in the integer)

Comment: So, back to the previous answer : O(ln n) operations if we dont allow magical operations like "compute log in O(1)" or "fetch the result from the big table".

Answer (score 3):

If log operation is O(1), so first, we can invert the number, plus one then take the log base 2 to get the result.

For example

> 1111110000000 -> invert -> 0000001111111 -> plus one -> 0000010000000 -> take log of base 2 -> 8

So the result is 8.

We can also create a Map of power of 2 to get rid of the log operation.

Answer (score 0):

A sorted string of zeros and ones can represented as 2 counts -- the number of zeros and the number of ones.

Obviously finding the position of the first zero is quite easy with such a representation -- it's just the number of ones.

Comment: how do you know how many number of zeros and ones? You have to go thru the list which costs O(n) right there.

Comment: The interviewer mentioned converting the string to a number, which will take O(n) regardless...  You might as well convert it into the *right* number instead of something artificially complicated

Comment: I should add:  Having conducted many such interviews, I think it's very unlikely that this was the starting point in the line of questioning.  More likely this came up somewhere in a multi-step process, and at some earlier point it would have been better just to count zeros and ones instead of building a string at all.